# how can I use ECDH for encryption in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption

I have developed an Android app which uses 128-bit ECDH key to encrypt/decrypt data (using bouncy castle project). Now we are going to develop the same app for iOS and I am looking for ECDH library in iOS. How can I use ECDH for iOS 6.0+? Is there any implementations?

Comment: This is mostly a question asking for a library/off-site resource and therefore off-topic. It is better to ask *how* to do something instead of asking for a library. You can edit your question so that it won't be closed.

Comment: @ArtjomB While that is true is is essentially never good practice to write your own cryptographic primitives, the chance of an error is to high. One needs a well better implementation. In such implementations not one error or oversight is acceptable.

Comment: @Zaph True, but providing a primitives library will not prevent potential pitfalls in designing your own protocol.

Comment: Also true but separate problems. I have a friend who designs cryptographic security protocols full time but does not write any code.

Comment: @hkazemi Please submit a bug report: http://bugreport.apple.com requisition ECDH support on iOS.